# Terminator 1.91 change tab theme/color using gtk3 css

Tags: ubuntu, gtk3, terminator

I have been trying to change the tab theme (i.e. color, height) etc. I have been googling, and found a writeup [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664466/how-to-change-the-design-of-tab-in-terminator), but this does not seem to work for either terminator, or terminal. But the focus is on Terminator.

OS's tried are Ubuntu 18.04 and Mint. I am installing Terminator 1.91 from source (avoiding distro to have truecolor support).

Comment: I am having the same problem. I was using Linux Mint 18.3 and it was working fine. Now I installed Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) and it's no longer working. I think it's due to gtk-3.20 changes, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 9):

After some trial and error using the GTK Inspector (GTK_DEBUG=interactive terminator), I found that it works if the css looks like this:

```
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked {
...
}

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab {
...
}
```

Note the "checked" instead of "active" and the missing dot on notebook.

Edit: this is with Mint 19 and the terminator from the repository, version 1.91-1.

Comment: Thanks @Radu, I tried what you suggested, both with and without the debugger, but so cigar. My CSS is pretty simple.. here is the example .terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked { background-color: red; } .terminator-terminal-window notebook tab { border-radius: 0px; padding: 3px; background-color: shade(#222, 1); }

Comment: interestingly, in my OS, Mint 18, if i change `.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab` to `.terminator-terminal-window .notebook tab`, i can adjust the height of the tab bar, but nothing else in terms of colors

Comment: Hm, very strange. Mine was with Mint 19 (beta) which is based on Ubuntu 18.04. In 18.3, something like .notebook tab {} worked (though it might affect things other than terminator).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Terminator 1.91

Comment: Can someone please tell me where do I change these settings? is it a config file stored somewhere?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader  For me the file was `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. The linked page in the initial question discusses the file location.